# How can I reduce the .ttf file size to reduce overall size of PDF generated by PDFJet library in JAVA?

Tags: pdf, fonts, fontforge

i have one .ttf file where i only stored the required glyph. can we reduce it's size further?

i tried FontForge to do some editing on font's weight and other value like removing overlapping and making it simpler with builtin feature but unable to see drastic change.

Comment: Some of the TrueType tables are not required in a PDF - the required ones are listed in the standard. But a PDF library like PDFJet should be removing those when embedding the font. Can you supply the font for us to play with?

Comment: By supply, I mean can you upload it somewhere and link to it...

Comment: @johnwhitington sorry, it's my first time asking things here, here is the file link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PlUF8fVyAN1_NhARIa8DqDZDG_ckbWXN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your font has been subset - it contains only the glyphs you require. That's most of the space gone. You can verify this by loading into FontForge. Your file does contain some tables which are not required by PDF - but those should be removed automatically when embedding in a  PDF. Can you upload the PDF from PDFJet with this font embedded?

Comment: my question is so we have more scope to reduce this .ttf file to see overall effect in pdf file?